# http https - 404 not found - reverse proxy problem

Tags: node.js, express, nginx-reverse-proxy

I deploy a Mean app with nodejs and express.

I made a reverse proxy with nginx.

`

```
 location /soc/ {
                root /capza_app/back/;
                index index.js;
#               proxy_set_header X-Real-IP;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                proxy_set_header AccesControl-Allow-Origin *;
                proxy_pass http://ip:3000/;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
```

`

I call my api in front here:
`apiUrl = 'https://mydomain/soc/transaction/'`

After all go in back in my index.js:
`app.use('/soc/transaction', TransactionController);`

My index send in my controller.

I have 404 error.
Without the reverse proxy, i have Mixed Content: The page at https as loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint http.

maybe routes problems but I don't know what i am do wrong.

Thanks

I try to change my route, chang my reverse proxy

Comment: Try `proxy_pass http://ip:3000/soc/;`

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work. I have error  gateway time out